# Using xlpastevalues in Access VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, copy-paste

I am working in Access and need to pull data from an Excel file. The file is very large with several sheets that I don't need, so I want to take the values from one sheet and put them in a new workbook in order to simplify/speed up later calculations. Currently, it is including formatting along with the values and some of my later macros are not working even though they worked when I manually pasted the values into the new sheet. I tried running this directly in Excel (removing the references to the Excel.Application variable) and it worked fine. Is there something different I should be doing since this is being run in Access?

```
Private Sub CopyImportFile()
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim SourceBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim SourceSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ImportBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim ImportSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SourceSheetPath As String

SourceSheetPath = "File Path"


Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set SourceBook = GetObject(SourceSheetPath)
Set SourceSheet = SourceBook.Worksheets("Data Tape")
Set ImportBook = xl.Workbooks.Add()
SourceSheet.UsedRange.Copy
ImportBook.Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
xl.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="New File Path"
SourceBook.Close False
ImportBook.Close
Set xl = Nothing
Set ImportBook = Nothing
Set SourceBook = Nothing
Set ImportSheet = Nothing
```

Comment: Try using `ImportBook.Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).PasteSpecial -4163` as you are using late binding and xlPasteValues will not be recognized by Access VBA.

Comment: `Dim ImportBook As Excel.Workbook` isn't late binding. @sktneer

Comment: Do you have [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of the module? If not, add it.

Comment: @Andre Didn't actually look at the declaration section, just looked at `CreateObject("Excel.Application")' :)

Comment: What do you mean with _not working_? Share errors, unexpected behaviour, or clarify that it just does nothing.

Comment: @sktneer Changing xlPasteValues to the numerical value worked - thanks!

Comment: Then I **strongly** recommend to use Option Explicit. The problem would have showed up directly in form of a compile error. -- It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time. 
To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor.

Comment: @CCooper Glad it worked.